# Print diamond shape multiline textbox in Visual Basic using loops in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have to write a program which on button click, generates a diamond shape. The diamond shape must be of size 32 (rows and columns) and each row/column increments by +/- 2 beginning at 1.

Here is what I have come up with so far, how can I display this diamond in a multiline textbox?

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To 15 Step 2
        If row = i Or _
        column = i Then
            TextBox1.Lines(i) = "O"
        End If
    Next

    For o As Integer = 16 To 32 Step -2
        If row = o Or _
            column = o Then
            TextBox1.Lines(o) = "O"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Not looking for a full solution here, just a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't row and column always zero?

Comment: Hint:  Try to think how many O's you will have to draw on each line and how that relates to the variable in your For loop.  You will have to come up with a calculation that takes the value of your loop counter (`i`) and determines the numbers of O's to draw.  Also, you should generally use `OrElse` instead of `Or`.  It doesn't make much difference in this code, but it short circuits and can have some increased performance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
    TextBox1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 9.0F)
    Dim n As Integer = 7
    For i As Integer = 1 To 15 Step 2
        Dim s As String = ""
        s = StrDup(n, " ") & StrDup(i, "*")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & s & vbCrLf
        n = n - 1
    Next
```